# Forest plot of adjusted hazard ratio using subgroup analysis

Tags: r

I have to generate a forest plot for subgroup analysis. However, whenever I run the model, it consistently generates a reference variable. What I actually want to observe is the effect of drugs across various subgroups:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(time = round(runif(1000, min = 1, max = 70)), 
                 status = round(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)),
                 drug = as.factor(c(rep("usual care",500),rep("proposed drug",500))),
                 sex = as.factor(round(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)))
            )

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status)~ drug+sex, data = df)
summary(model)
ggforest(model)
```

My output showing sex=0 as reference.
[image: My output showing sex=0 as reference.]

However, I want to draw following forest plot where there is not reference rather all subgroups.
[image: However, I want to draw following forest plot]

Comment: I don’t understand how one could do such a plot without a reference to establish the Null.